# Uploading Files in django-admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am making a project in django where only the **admin will be having the permission to upload files**. How can I modify the admin page so that option to upload files is only visible to admin? currently it is looking something like this. But I want an **upload files** option also below **add choice** action.

[image: Django Admin]

Comment: What is the relation ? Is there are image for every choice ?

Comment: Basically i am giving a csv file of choices and i want all the choices to be created through that file

Comment: Where the image comes ? do you have a model for that ?

Comment: Yes I have created a model for that